# Python: Inserting list of tuples in SQL Database and add an auto-incrementing id field

Tags: python, insert, sqlite

I got a list of 20 tuples which I need store in a sqlite DB.

I use this code to create the table

> curs.execute("CREATE TABLE test(id MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT, POI text, Address text, Phone text, Website text, PRIMARY KEY (id))")

I would use

> curs.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)',var)

to store a single tuple in the DB...

But I just get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> sqlite3.OperationalError: table test has 5 columns but 4 values were supplied

So how do I add the tuple and the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
curs.execute('INSERT INTO test(POI, Address, Phone, Website) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)',var)
```

Comment: Try changing that to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT it needs an integer

Comment: Oops.. i thought i changed `MEDIUMINT` to `INTEGER`. Sorry